# Upload courses to Moodle via FTP

Tags: ftp, backup, moodle

I have a very large Moodle `.mbz` backup file of a single course - Slightly over 1GB. I need to upload this backup to the server, but of course the file manager Moodle provides won't allow me to do this as the file is too big.

So I was wondering if it would be possible to upload the backup via FTP to some folder in `moodledata` to then use the backup manager to restore the course, if so, where should I upload it/where are the backups stored?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, figured it out. The way to do it by using [repositories](https://docs.moodle.org/20/en/File_system_repository). You need to create a folder in moodledata with the name "repository", then create a folder inside that with whatever name you want. Upload your backup into this folder.

Then, enable the File System Repositories plugin in Settings > Site administration > Plugins > Repositories > Manage Repositories. Change the drop down for "File Repository" to "Enabled and visible, then click the settings button next to the dropdown.

Then, use the UI to create a new repository instance, selecting the folder you created earlier. Then save, and that repository should show up in the file picker menu.

Comment: Please update your answer to be more clear: 

"Change the drop down for "File Repository" to "Enabled and visible".

Answer (score 4):

Just had a go at this, looks like a few things have changed since this was written, but is mostly correct.

Starting from the Dashboard, go through the 'Site Administration > Plugins > Repositories > Manage Repositories' path as in James' answer, but 'File Repository' is now 'File System'.

Once the dropdown is set to Enabled and Visible, you can go into settings and click 'Create a repository instance'. From here you should be able to work out what to do provided the folder is in the right location.